# Is $a \lceil \frac b c \rceil \geq \lceil \frac {ab} c \rceil$? ($a, b \geq 0$ and $c > 0$)

Tags: inequality, modular-arithmetic, fractions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Comparing $a \big\lceil \frac b c \big\rceil$ vs $\big\lceil \frac {ab} c \big\rceil$, where

- $a, b, c$ are integers with $a, b \geq 0$ and $c > 0$
- $a = q_a c + r_a$ where $0 \leq r_a < c$
- $b = q_b c + r_b$ where $0 \leq r_b < c$

Then

$$
\begin{align}
a \bigg\lceil \frac b c \bigg\rceil
&= a \bigg\lceil \frac {q_b c + r_b} c \bigg\rceil \\
&= a \bigg\lceil q_b + \frac {r_b} c \bigg\rceil \\
&= a \big( q_b + \big[ r_b \neq 0 \big] \big) \\
&= a \big( q_b + \big[ b \not\mid c \big] \big) \\
&= a q_b + a \big[ b \not\mid c \big]
\end{align}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
\bigg\lceil \frac {ab} c \bigg\rceil
&= \bigg\lceil \frac {a (q_b c + r_b)} c \bigg\rceil \\
&= \bigg\lceil a q_b + \frac {a r_b} c \bigg\rceil \\
&= a q_b + \bigg\lceil \frac {a r_b} c \bigg\rceil \\
&= a q_b + \bigg\lceil \frac {(q_a c + r_a) r_b} c \bigg\rceil \\
&= a q_b + \bigg\lceil q_a r_b + \frac {r_a r_b} c \bigg\rceil \\
&= a q_b + q_a r_b + \bigg\lceil \frac {r_a r_b} c \bigg\rceil \\
&= b q_a + q_b r_a + \bigg\lceil \frac {r_a r_b} c \bigg\rceil
\end{align}
$$

where $[cond]$ equals $1$ if condition $cond$ is true and $0$ otherwise.

---

Case 1. If $r_b = 0$, then

$$
a \bigg\lceil \frac b c \bigg\rceil = a q_b = \bigg\lceil \frac {ab} c \bigg\rceil
$$

---

Case 2. If $r_b \neq 0$ and $r_a = 0$, then

$$
a \bigg\lceil \frac b c \bigg\rceil = a q_b + a
$$

and

$$
\bigg\lceil \frac {ab} c \bigg\rceil = b q_a
$$

---

Case 3. If $r_b \neq 0$ and $r_a \neq 0$, then

$$
a \bigg\lceil \frac b c \bigg\rceil = a q_b + a
$$

and

$$
\bigg\lceil \frac {ab} c \bigg\rceil = a q_b + q_a r_b + \bigg\lceil \frac {r_a r_b} c \bigg\rceil
$$

---

Can we say anything further about Case 2. and Case 3.?

---

Noting that $0 \leq r_a, r_b \leq c - 1$, we can conclude

$$
0 \leq \bigg\lceil \frac {r_a r_b} c \bigg\rceil \leq c - 1
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that $\left\lceil\frac{b}{c}\right\rceil \ge \frac{b}{c}$. Multiply by $a$ to get $a\left\lceil\frac{b}{c}\right\rceil \ge \frac{a\ b}{c}$.

Since $a\left\lceil\frac{b}{c}\right\rceil$ is an integer greater than or equal to $\frac{a\ b}{c}$ then it's greater than or equal to the smallest integer greater or equal to $\frac{a\ b}{c}$, that is $a\left\lceil\frac{b}{c}\right\rceil \ge \left\lceil\frac{a\ b}{c}\right\rceil$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 0):

No. If $a <1$, then this may not be true. Consider $a=.5 ,$ $b=c= 1$. Then right side is 1 and left side is .5.

---

If we assume a,b, and c are integers, then the statement is true.

Let $b= nc + r$, $ 0 <  r < 1$ (if r=0 then we have equality), $n$ a non-negative integer.  Then left is $a(n+1)=an + a$ and right is $\lceil a(n+r/c) \rceil=\lceil an+ar/c \rceil$. $a \geq \lceil ar/c \rceil$. The result follows.

Comment: Thanks. You're right (upvoted). Sorry, I forgot to say that $a, b, c$ are integers.

Comment: In that case, it is probably true.

Comment: After the edits, I think there are mistakes. E.g. left side is only $an + a$ if $a \not \mid c$. Otherwise, left side is just $an$. And your right side is missing $\frac 1 c$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).