# Figuring out best lower bound for Leetcode #2187. Minimum Time to Complete Trips

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions, upper-lower-bounds, integer-programming

The [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-time-to-complete-trips/description/):

> You are given an array `time` where `time[i]` denotes the time taken by the `i`th bus to complete one trip.
>
> Each bus can make multiple trips successively; that is, the next trip can start immediately after completing the current trip. Also, each bus operates independently; that is, the trips of one bus do not influence the trips of any other bus.
>
> You are also given an integer `totalTrips`, which denotes the number of trips all buses should make in total. Return the minimum time required to complete at least `totalTrips` trips.

Let

- $m$ = `min(time)`
- $N$ = `len(time)`
- $R$ = `totalTrips`

I know $mR$ is a good upper bound for the answer. What is a good lower bound?

Assume the best case scenario where `all(time[i] = m for i in range(N))`. Then, it takes $m$ time units to complete $N$ trips. If fractional trips were allowed to count towards the trip count, then $R$ trips could be completed in $\frac {mR} N$ time units (note this number might not be whole. So, I was wondering if both

- $m \big\lceil \frac R N \big\rceil$
- $\big\lceil \frac {mR} N \big\rceil$

are valid lower bounds and if so, which one gives the higher lower bound (I asked about this [separately](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4656423/833760)? I feel like $m \big\lceil \frac R N \big\rceil$ is a valid upper bound and usually $\geq \big\lceil \frac {mR} N \big\rceil$, but can't quite prove it.

My solution passes all tests using either lower bound, but that's not proof that both lower bounds are valid -- maybe one of the lower bounds is invalid and a set of inputs that would make it fail (a counterexample) is not one of the test cases in the test suite.

Solution:

```
# Binary Search solution
class Solution:
    def minimumTime(self, times: List[int], R: int) -> int:
        def possible(T):
            '''Whether it's possible to do R trips in T time units.'''
            return sum(T // time for time in times) >= R
        m = min(times)
        N = len(times)
        LO = m if R <= N else ceil(m * R / N)   # **lower bound 1**
        # LO = m if R <= N else m * ceil(R / N) # **lower bound 2**
        HI = m * R # upper bound
        # INVARIANT:
        # - It's not possible to do R trips in LO-1 time units
        # - It's possible to do R trips in HI time units
        while LO < HI:
            MID = (LO + HI) >> 1
            if possible(MID):
                HI = MID
            else:
                LO = MID + 1
        # LO == HI
        # It's not possible to do R trips in LO-1 time units
        # It's possible to do R trips in LO time units
        return LO
```

Comment: You might want to rethink your alleged upper bound. It seems to imply that every trip can be made by any bus using the time of the fastest bus.

Comment: @prubin $mR$ is the time it would take the fastest bus (recall, $m = $ `min(time)`) to make $R$ consecutive (back-to-back) trips, so it is a valid upper bound.

Comment: OK. It was unclear to me that each bus could run any and all routes.

Comment: Also, your upper bound is contingent on there being no deadheading (lost time between consecutive routes), which was not explicitly stated.

Comment: @prubin you might have missed this part "Each bus can make multiple trips successively; that is, the next trip can start immediately after completing the current trip." At any rate, thanks for the comment.s

Comment: I saw that but took it to mean that after a stop the bus was immediately available for another trip (did not need to go through any delay for cleaning, refueling etc.). If the last trip was $a \rightarrow b$ and the next trip was $b \rightarrow c$ there would be no loss of time; but if the next trip after $a \rightarrow b$ was $c \righarrow d$ then presumably it would take some time to move the bus from $b$ to $c.$ (If you can teleport the buses, you can presumably teleport the passengers and skip the buses entirely.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any feasible solution, you can shorten it by speeding up all buses to have trip time $m.$ Having done that, you can speed it up further by having all buses run simultaneously to the extent possible, and by eliminating any deadheading times (transit times between trips for a single bus). That gives overall time $m \big\lceil \frac R N \big\rceil$, so it is indeed a valid lower bound. The inequality $m \big\lceil \frac R N \big\rceil \ge \big\lceil \frac {mR} N \big\rceil$ was proved in an answer to your other (linked) question.